# Why my select query returns "more than 5000 records"?

Tags: orientdb

I have t_users class with the following schema:

- name (string)
- uid (long)

I have around 100K records for that class and when I want to get a specific user using its id, Orientdb tells me that my query returns more thant 5K records, so it returns nothing.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT FROM t_users where uid = 123456
```

Comment: I guess you uid field is unique. Define a unique index on it:
http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Create-Index.html
CREATE INDEX t_users.uid UNIQUE

Comment: Indeed, it is unique...but I don't understand why I should use an index for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and return the data by using limits and inspect the data returned to try and conclude an answer.

[Documentation - Limiting](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Pagination.html)

```
SELECT FROM <target> [WHERE ...] SKIP <records-to-skip> LIMIT <max-records>
```

Comment: I have the same result:
Query 'SELECT FROM t_user WHERE uid = 123456 LIMIT 10' fetched more than 50000 records: to speed up the execution, create an index or change the query to use an existent index